# Accessing the new Notification Settings in Android 4.3 through Code

Tags: android, notifications

How can I access this through code? So I can open it for the users automatically and they don't have to hunt through the Security settings to enable it.

I am unable to find it in Android Studio using `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.<>));`, where <> is the list of setting screens.

[image: Notification Access Screen]

Image courtesy of Android Police

Comment: It is possible that this will only appear on the Security screen in Settings when 1+ notification listeners are installed.

Comment: I've installed my app with the Notification Listener as well as "ActiveNotifications for Android" app (which has the settings screen pop up when you open the app) but it still doesn't show up.

Comment: I feel really dumb, it does show up once you have one installed... however I would still like to automatically open it for the user so they don't have to hunt for it. will edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is [an outstanding bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58030) in Android 4.3 where the notification listener screen action is not listed in `Settings`. The current workaround is:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Comment: I used this in my app but now it opens every time the app starts. Is there a way to make it open only if the user hasn't selected the app for access?

Comment: @AbhyudayaSrinet: I have not played around with a `NotificationListenerService`. You would need to find out whether you are enabled as a listener or not, and only start the activity if you are not enabled as a listener. I have not researched this area to know how exactly to do that.

Comment: Ok I found what I needed.. In case anyone needs directions in future, this is the [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097583/check-for-access-to-notifications-using-notificationlistenerservice)
and I also added this line in my main activity  
    if(!NLService.isNotificationAccessEnabled)
        startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));

Answer (score 2):

The [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58030) that @CommonsWare mentioned [has been fixed as of Android 5.1 (API 22)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.0ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS). You can now use this to bring the user to the *Notification access* screen:

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));`

I've tested this across multiple Genymotion instances (4.3, 4.4, and 5.1) as well as a Galaxy S3 running 4.3, and this solution has worked perfectly in each case.

Strangely however Android Studio does give me a warning when I use this field on pre-API 22 projects, despite the fact that it works without problems:

> Field requires API 22 (current min is 18): android.provider.Settings#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS

I believe that this warning should be able to be safely ignored, similarly to how you can use values from [Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) on any version of the platform.

Link to the documentation: [Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)