# Is there a way an app can check if it is allowed to access notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to implement an NotificationListenerService to get access to all notifications that are posted to the notification bar.

I understand that I need to enable access to the Notifications in the Settings with this call:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

Is there a way to check if the user activated Notification access for my app?

Comment: Once [android issue 58030](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58030) is merged, we'll no longer have to use a hardcoded string here. Hopefully it gets in soon!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185207/1696171

Answer (score 14):

I managed to find a slight hack to solve this. If you check the source of `Settings.Secure`, you will see that `ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS` is annotated with `@hide`. I don't know if this is intentional or not. On a related topic, CommonsWare does mention in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18212666/362298) that there is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58030) preventing the starting of this setting so I guess is unintentional.

Anyway, to work around this, all I did was to fetch the current list of enabled notification listeners using the string value of `ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS`:

```
String enabledListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), 
    "enabled_notification_listeners");
```

Then you just have to check if your service is in the list.

I did not test this on all API >= 18 yet but it is working on Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Checking to see if your service is in the list is very easy, please check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21392852/823952

Comment: Didn't work for me on 4.4.4, but I tried on Genymotion Emulator

Answer (score 2):

Probably for API 19 (4.4) and higher.
Although I tried on API 21 (5.0)

```
String enabledListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), 
"enabled_notification_listeners");
```

"secured" was turning RED. If you want to use it you have to use:

```
String enabledNotificationListeners = 
  android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), 
  "enabled_notification_listeners");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

Comment: This is to check if your notifications are being blocked by Android at the user's request. The question is about the NotificationListenerService (checking if you can listen to notifications).

Answer (score 0):

**Use listnerConnected  boolean in your Service class**

```
public class NotifyListener extends NotificationListenerService{    
    public static boolean listnerConnected = false;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(name,"onBind Called");
        listnerConnected = true;
        return super.onBind(intent);
}   

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {       
        super.onDestroy();        
        Log.e("destroy", "called");
        listnerConnected = false;

    }
}
```