# Android Enable/Disable Notification access Automatically

Tags: android, notifications, settings

Hi  how can I enable/disable the notification access settings for my
app automatically?

Comment: in the option in settings>security to allow your app to access to notifications!!

Comment: i'm reading the notification from whatsapp!

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using following code:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
String setting = Settings.Secure.ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS;
String permissionString = Settings.Secure.getString(cr, setting);
if(permissionString == null || !permissionString.contains("com.abc.xyz"))
{
    ComponentName analytics = new ComponentName("com.abc.xyz", "com.abc.xyz.LMN");
    if(permissionString == null)
        permissionString = "";
    else
        permissionString += ":";
    permissionString += analytics.flattenToString();
    Settings.Secure.putString(cr, setting, permissionString);
}
```

Note that the application needs to be a System application or signed with the same key used by framework res apk in order write in Setting.Secure database.

Comment: what does this "com.abc.xyz" means?

Comment: Its the package name of your application like com.whatsapp for WhatsApp

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible.You have to go settings and u have to on.You can give intent to settings like

startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));

Comment: The following post is more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212209/accessing-the-new-notification-settings-in-android-4-3-through-code