# Enable/Disable Notification Access programmatically

Tags: android, notifications, settings

I want to enable/ disable notification access for an specific app automatically and programmatically (without user have to move the switch in the settings).

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046143/9469827 ,but it seems that `Settings.Secure.ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS` is not supported anymore.

Is it even possible in 7.0 and higher?