# How to enable Notification access on button click without opening system setting?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an app in which i have to enable notification access for my app on button click without opening System setting screen. How do i archeive.

code:-

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

but don't want to open system setting.

Comment: What do you mean by notification access. Are you using Firebase cloud messaging or any other provider?

Comment: To read all notification we have to get permission from system.

Comment: So you want to read all the notifications of all apps that come to the system

Comment: yes ............

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757878/how-to-read-all-the-coming-notifications-in-android

Comment: That what i am doing...........but i want to enable notification access without opening system setting

Comment: In my opinion you can't do that. Since its a system functionality, to gain any access you need to manually take User's approval

Comment: What permissions do you declare in your manifest? And how are you declaring the NotificationListenerService in your manifest?

Comment: <service
            android:name=".Services.CNotificationHandlerService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Comment: Hmm. That looks fine, but I think the user still has to manually enable the system setting at some point. You might be able to get away with just asking them once, and then checking that it's still enabled? This thread has some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097583/check-for-access-to-notifications-using-notificationlistenerservice